# rsync - exclude all directories except a few

Tags: rsync

There appear to be a lot of SF and SO questions out there about this, but none seem to match my requirements.

```
source_dir/
  some_dir/
  another_dir/
  some_file.php
  some_other_file.txt
  include_this_dir/
  include_that_dir/
  yet_another_dir/
```

So I want to rsync two of those dirs, while excluding the rest. It's important that we exclude **all but** those two dirs, because there might be other files that at some later date are added to the source_dir and would need to be excluded without being explicitly listed.

I tried:

```
rsync -av --dry-run --delete --exclude="source_dir/*" (or just "*") --include-from="include.txt" source_dir dest_dir
```

And my include.txt had

```
  include_this_dir/
  include_that_dir/
```

and also I tried adding

```
  source_dir/
```

No joy. Nothing gets included at all.

Comment: You might try to put the include option before the exclude option. Im not sure but rsync may stop checking after the first match.

Comment: I think I tried that before, but it's worth another go

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A simple filter should do the trick. To build on the prior answer with a proper example -- Explicitly include the parent(s), plus all (**) sub folders and files. Then exclude everything else. Here's `filter.txt`:

```
+ /include_this_dir/
+ /include_this_dir/**
+ /include_that_dir/
+ /include_that_dir/**
- /**
```

With the command line:

```
rsync -av --dry-run --filter="merge filter.txt" source_dir/ dest_dir/
```

Would result in:

```
sending incremental file list
created directory dest_dir
./
include_that_dir/
include_that_dir/somefile.txt
include_that_dir/subdir/
include_this_dir/

sent 202 bytes  received 65 bytes  534.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```

Comment: You can reduce it further with three "*", like `+ /include_this_dir/***`, which means `+ /include_this_dir/
+ /include_this_dir/**`

Comment: This example works, but if you are tarteting files in folders several levels deep, you need to include all parent folders up to the target files.  Like this:
`+ /first_dir/
+ /first_dir/second_dir/
+ /first_dir/second_dir/**
- /**`

Answer (score 3):

To cite from the `rsync` manual section `FILTER RULES`:

> [..] the first matching pattern is acted on: if it is
>   an exclude pattern, then that file is skipped; if it is an include
>   pattern then that filename is not skipped; if no matching pattern is
>   found, then the filename is not skipped.

Thus, it might be your best option to read your filter rules from a file, and sort them accordingly. Example:

```
CW+ source_dir/include_this_dir/
CW+ source_dir/include_that_dir/
CW- source_dir/
```

Your can specify the filter rules file with the `--filter=` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

New command string which creates --included dirs and copies it's content dir and/or files, but ONLY 2 DIRS DEEP. Why?

```
rsync -avid --progress ~/MyDocuments/'Inet Publishing'/ --recursive --include='LandisTwo (2019)' --include='LandisTwo (2020) {backup}' --include='*.*' --exclude='**/' e6420:/home/landis/Media/2TBackup/Backups/MyDocuments/"Inet\ Publishing"/ | tee -a ~/logs/Backup-InetPublishing_2020.txt
```

- I've descovered that the Directories are Created, but NO FILES are copied to them (no recursion). files in parent are copied, but Not sub dirs - working on it.

this works for me, from workstation to server, backing up (rysnc) my personal site to another server in addition to the whole directory w/ all sites when rysnc'ing parent ../Inet\ Publishing (the 'n' in -avin is 'Dry-Run', remove.).

The --exclude */ is all other directories in 'Inet Publishing/' and seems to have to be After --include per man rsync process order ( if before --include, then Everything is --excluded and no further tokens are processed, at least that's how i read it and in practice dry runs when coming up with this. ).

This is actually one line out of one of my scripts i run with cron. *obviously, the destination host can be an IP, i have the hosts defined in /etc/hosts and have ssh key pairs,,, so i use the host name.

<del>rsync -avin --progress ~/MyDocuments/'Inet Publishing'/ --include='LandisTwo (2019)' --include='LandisTwo (2020) {backup}' --exclude='*/' e6420:/home/landis/Media/2TBackup/Backups/MyDocuments/ | tee -a ~/logs/Backup-InetPublishing_2020.txt</del>